# How can I retrieve the number of like_count with the new facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-like

I am using a like button for my web site, got it from the facebook page using the iframe version. I want to show the number of people like my site only when this number is bigger that 50. I was thinking that I could use an fql.query for getting the like_count and if this is bigger that 50 then show it. I don't want to create a Facebook App in the developers page so I don't have an App id etc. 
What I have done is:

```
$data = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query', 
    'query' => 'select  like_count from link_stat where  url="http://www.mysite.com',
    'callback'  => ''
);
```

But I do not know how to store the results in a PHP variable and if at the end I can display them only when I want to.

I have searched a lot about it and not find something yet so I would appreciate a lot if someone could help me.

Comment: "I don't want to create a Facebook App in the developers page so I don't have an App id etc" --- you have no choice. You **have to** register there to be able to perform API requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a request to http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.mysite.com/ in Javascript, and it will return a JSON object with the number of shares and comments thus:

```
{
    "id": "http://www.mysite.com/",
    "shares": 70503,
    "comments": 1
}
```

That shares number should match the number you will get in the like button.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the graph-api without any access_token, e.g.

[https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D"facebook.com"](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27facebook.com%27)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know if you do need to register an App. I know you can do some things using the Graph API without an App ID (although obviously if it's a closed group or event I'm guessing you'd need to be able to get an OAuth access_token for that). I haven't used FQL at all, but I'm pretty sure that you don't need an App ID to do some things.

In answer to the OP, this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat uses the $facebook object that they seem to use throughout. Take a look at this code on github: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

That might help.